# Available methods for classifying long text sequences in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, natural-language

I am looking to solve a multi-class classification problem with long sequences of text with some rows having 1000's of tokens. Some of the state of the art methods such as BERT have a token limit and I was wondering what is currently being done to handle longer text sequences when dealing with classification?

Answer (score 2):

The good old machine learning approaches still work pretty well. At least as a baseline, I would definitely try removing stop words and representing the texts as bag-of-words vectors or TF-IDF vectors and train a classifier on top of that.

Depending on how much data you have, you can proceed to some simple neural nets (RNN/CNN) on top of pre-trained word embeddings. This should scale pretty well for long texts.

The solution that can potentially get you the best result is similar to what people do in pointer networks for text summarization. Sentence-split your data and process each sentence with BERT independently. This will give you a sequence of vectors, that you can again process using an RNN or CNN and then classify.